# Craft install via composer: install to public_html?

Tags: install, composer

When I do `composer create-project craftcms/craft`, it will create a `web` folder. My webroot is called `public_html` though. Can I change this somehow, or should I make a symlink?

Or simply don't use composer to install in that case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just rename `web/` to `public_html/`, or move all the files inside `web/` into `public_html/`. (Don’t forget to move the `.htaccess` and `.env` files, if the latter.)

As long as the location of the `public_html/` folder is in the same place as the `web/` folder was, you don’t need to change anything else.

```
my-project.test/
├── config/
├── ...
└── public_html/
    ├── index.php
    └── ...
```

If you need to change the location to something like this:

```
my-project.test/
├── craft/
│   ├── config/
│   └── ...
└── public_html/
    ├── index.php
    └── ...
```

Then just make sure that your `CRAFT_BASE_PATH` constant points to the right base path (`craft/`).

```php
// old:
define('CRAFT_BASE_PATH', dirname(__DIR__));

// new:
define('CRAFT_BASE_PATH', dirname(__DIR__) . '/craft');
```

Comment: But won't that break `composer update` for later maintenance?

Comment: No it won't. Composer update installs everything into `/vendor`. All my projects use `/public` instead of `/web`.

Comment: Ok! So that would also be a valid setup: `home/craft` (with `config`, `modules`, `storage`, `template` and `vendor`, not accessible via web), `home/public_html` (with the content of `web` and a modified `CRAFT_BASE_PATH`)?

Comment: In that case just make sure that the `CRAFT_BASE_PATH` constant in `public_html/index.php` is pointed at the `craft/` folder.

Comment: Just updated my answer to show what that would look like.